# Are Fermi problems allowed on physics.stackexchange?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

I am new to physics.stackexchange.com, but I not new to Stack Exchange per se. I asked a question which I consider a [Fermi problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_problem):

> In physics or engineering education, a Fermi problem [...] is an estimation problem designed to teach dimensional analysis or approximation of extreme scientific calculations, and such a problem is usually a back-of-the-envelope calculation. The estimation technique is named after physicist Enrico Fermi as he was known for his ability to make good approximate calculations with little or no actual data.

One of the features of such a problem is the fact that the person solving the problem has to come up with assumptions and argue why she/he has chosen them. I asked my second question and explicitly stated that I would be interested in other physicists' approaches and assumptions, in order to avoid a closure-because-of-missing details, and now exactly that happened - the question got closed for that reason.

Therefore:

**Are Fermi problems in scope of physics.stackexchange?** If not, why not? If yes, could somebody guide me what I need to change so that my question can be reopened, please?

Comment: Related/Possible duplicates: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6996/50583, https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6020/50583

Comment: @ACuriousMind Looks like the answer to "Fermi-questions in scope?" is "it depends on the level of details". So what about my question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/609010/bernoulli-effect-of-prairie-dog-caves - could somebody tell me please *what* details would have been required to re-open?